# Protractor : string retrieved in promise of getAttribute() is null

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, promise, protractor

Saying that I have to verify the status of a checkbox

```
element(by.css('input')).getAttribute("checked").then(function(isChecked:string) {
      expect(isChecked).toEqual(pExpected.toString());
    }),
```

In my test, I verify that the checkbox is checked by default. Everything works fine here. Then I uncheck the checkbox

```
element(by.css('input')).click();
```

And recall the function to verify that the checkbox is unchecked. This time, the variable `isChecked` is null. I've also tried

```
var cb = element(by.css('input'));
cb .click().then(function(){
  cb .getAttribute("checked").then(function(isChecked:string){
    expect(isChecked).toEqual("false");
  })
});
```

Nothing changed. I cannot understand what's going on here. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You might want to read on the difference between attributes and properties - the checked attribute is either not there or it is there and it is checked. The checked property is either true or false. (IIRC)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Hi, thanks for the comment, I checked with the element inspector. The property "checked" should be what I have to get. But how can I access to the property using Protractor? Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Use something like-
`expect(element(by.css('input')).isSelected()).toBeFalsy()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way, use isEnabled instead of getAttribute and toBeFalsy instead of toEqual to verify the status of a checkbox.

```
var cb = element(by.css('input'));
    cb .click().then(function(){
        cb .isEnabled().then(function(Checked){
            expect(Checked).toBeFalsy();
        })
    });
```